# I'm trying to run npm install bcrypt with npm version v8.10.0 but I keep receiving the following issue. Using Mac Mojave not sure if that helps

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package, npm-install

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/josephmonreal/node_modules
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/josephmonreal/package.json'
npm WARN josephmonreal No description
npm WARN josephmonreal No repository field.
npm WARN josephmonreal No README data
npm WARN josephmonreal No license field.

npm ERR! path /Users/josephmonreal/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/josephmonreal/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/josephmonreal/node_modules'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/Users/josephmonreal/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/josephmonreal/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/josephmonreal/.npm/_logs/2019-10-07T02_13_49_224Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What's the exact command you use to install?

Comment: I've tried:
npm install bcrypt
npm install bcrypt-nodejs
npm install bcryptjs

I run into the same issue with each command

Comment: i tried npm install -g bcrypt and it seemed to work.